# What really light Ubuntu releases are there? 

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, software-recommendation

I want a really light Ubuntu release so I get as much as possible out of my computer.
I will only use this one for gaming, that's why I need to get as much out of my laptop as possible.

I want:

- Low cpu usage
- Low RAM usage
- 11.04
- 11.10
- 64-bit

Please list only one release per answer.

Comment: Subjective, and duplicate. However, since none of them seem to be well-maintained, I'll just link to the duplicate and let the mods decide. - http://askubuntu.com/questions/28965/how-to-configure-ubuntu-for-lightweight-low-memory-usage

Comment: If that is your question, then it *is* off-topic.

Comment: then it's not...

Comment: Then what is not? Then it is not a duplicate, or it is not on-topic?

Comment: it's not a duplicate because I want the lightest Ubuntu system, not a desktop environment that the question is about. and it's not off-topic since it's Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Lubuntu

Lubuntu is a lighter version of ubuntu that uses a different desktop environment: [LXDE](http://lxde.org/). It is of course less resource hungry than the default desktop environment in ubuntu.

Check out this wiki page for more information https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu ; it says Lubuntu can run on a Celeron computer with 128 MB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at XUbuntu 11.10?  So far it's the lightest one I've come across since I started using Ubuntu back with Hardy Heron.