# How to speed up my Ubuntu PC?

Tags: server, gnome, xubuntu, lubuntu, 20.04

I have a desktop PC. I installed 20.04, the new version of Ubuntu. But it is too slow. I have 2 GB of RAM and 3.00 GHz processor. How can I speed up my PC?

Comment: If you are running on 20.04, why is your question tagged 14.04?  14.04 reached End Of Life more than a year ago. But here:  https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-ubuntu-1310/

Comment: Your tags are somehow misleading.  The 14.04 tag should be removed before someone closes the question. (no EOL support). You should not be using gnome with 2gb ram, so remove that tag as well. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1248589/edit) your question and add the output of `lscpu` into it. We cannot help if you do no not share more information

Comment: Let's see: Check your startup critical-chain, check your memory usage and look for swapping, look at your error messages in /var/log. Use `top` to make sure you don't have a CPU bottleneck. Most folks are surprised how much RAM their web browsers use; often closing a tab or two is enough to make an enormous difference.

Answer (score 2):

With 2GB of RAM these days you might try several things :

- use **L**ubuntu
- go through the [Low RAM installation recommendations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems)
- change window manager to [openbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28965/how-to-configure-ubuntu-for-lightweight-low-memory-usage)
- disable all system services you do not need ( e.g. via `stacer`)
- switch to low-ram distros like [slax](https://www.slax.org/) / [porteus](http://www.porteus.org/) or [tinycore](https://www.slax.org/)

To sum it up: **2GB RAM is no fun**, unless you reduce the background noise to a minimum

Comment: Lubuntu, xubuntu or MATE would be better than GNOME, KDE or Budgie.  GNOME in particular is very heavy on resources